# My videos are not coming out clear

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video, screenshot

I've been using Abode Photoshop CC video editing for a while. Whenever I exported a video from photoshop. For some reason, the video doesn't come out clear. I've no idea why the video doesn't come out clear. Can anyone help?

**Updated:** One of my render settings
[image: Render Settings 1]

**Updated:** One of my video information:
[image: Video Info]

Comment: Hi Michelle. Can you include a screenshot of the settings you are using when exporting? That might help people understand what's going on a little better.

Comment: Okay! I will do that.

Comment: what are the original video settings / codec / framerate / size? Can you put a screenshot of a frame of the original video and the one you exported, where the issue is clearly visible? Have you tried changing all the settings, none of the settings produce a good result?

Comment: I try all the settings but none of them produced good results. One of my video information is added.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can give a sample of the result so that people can see what "not coming out clear" actually means

Comment: I can't. I still a newbie. In order to show more information, I need to gain 10 reputation points.